# ASP.NET Sum of column to string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to show the sum of a column as a string. What's wrong?
The only output I get from cmd.ExecuteReader(); seems to be: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader

```
       protected void TotalHours() {
        DatabaseConnection.Commandstring = ("SELECT SUM ([Time]) FROM tbl_login");
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseConnection.ConString)) {
            try {
                con.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(DatabaseConnection.Commandstring, con)) {
                    DatabaseConnection.result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    txt_TotalTime.Text = ("Total Time: " + DatabaseConnection.result.ToString());
                    con.Close();
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                con.Close();
                Debug.WriteLine("Error Selecting Time from Database " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `ExecuteReader` it is usually used to read multiple returned records through a reader. What you need is `ExecuteScalar` like:

```
  DatabaseConnection.result = (decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Remember to cast it to required type. It should be decimal since , it looks like you are doing caculation based on money.

Comment: Thank you! That worked!
The table in my DB is set to INT, but removing the cast worked fine :)
But it will contain money in the future, so you taught me something useful :)

Comment: @BPW, You are welcome, Just to add, with `int` you can't store decimal points in your table. It would depend on your requirements, but generally for money the data type used should be `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

If ypu want to use `reader` you have to *read*: `reader.Read()`; do not forget to *dispose* reader as well (put it into `using`):

```
try {
  using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseConnection.ConString)) {
    con.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(DatabaseConnection.Commandstring, con)) {
      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        if (reader.Read()) // you have to read
          txt_TotalTime.Text = String.Format("Total Time: ", reader.GetValue(0));
      }
    }
  }
}
catch (DbException ex) { // Bad style: do not catch ALL the exceptions
  Debug.WriteLine("Error Selecting Time from Database " + ex.Message);
}
```